# how to dual-boot ubuntu-touch with android

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-touch, android

I have been following the progress of the ubuntu-touch, mostly via [blog posts](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/?s=ubuntu-touch), and [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=ubuntu-touch)(am loving every video of it). But, as far as i can tell, popular apps like **WhatsApp**, **Viber**,  **etc...** are yet to be ported to the ubuntu-touch.

Apps like [**whosthere**](https://launchpad.net/whosthere)(WhatsApp replacement) has been discontinued.

**Question**: How can I dual-boot android with the ubuntu-touch.
**Note**: I'm using samsung galaxy s2 as my main phone.

Comment: What device do you have? We need to know this so that we can find the proper utility on the xda developers network.

Comment: @Dillmo, a samsung galaxy s2, as is stated in the question!

Answer (score 2):

If there is an Ubuntu port for your device, you might want to try [the dual boot feature](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2013/12/announcing-ubuntu-and-android-dual-boot-developer-preview/).

Answer (score 1):

There's an app at the Google store called [Boot Manager Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drx2.bootmanager) that promises to do what you ask. I never tried it myself though (I have an LG which is not supported), but it would be nice if it works with Touch. Give it a try and let us know.

Comment: The pro is €2.17, but, there is also a light(free) version: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drx2.bootmanager.lite&feature=search_result . on top of that, my samsung galaxy s2 is not on there supported devices list. Apart from not wanting to pay to get a free OS up and running, nor does it provide - or say, that they have - proof that it will get my dual-boot setup properly, on my S2. This doesn't really answer my question. But, I appreciate the effort :)

Answer (score 0):

- Check if your phones motherboard(sata) supports dual boot i.e the bus architecture from the host to the hardware, which it won't probably because the phone companies unlike computers keep things as simple as possible in order to get better efficiency in terms of battery and other things.
- Second thing is ROM, check for the custom dual boot ROM availability and your device's ROM capability.
- The third is arm processor which will be fine probably since even the android is using linux kernel just like Ubuntu.

**Warning:**

If dual boot is not possible, you may get the screen that Ubuntu is loading but will get stuck there and you will have to forcefully shutdown which will crash your android too.